# How to remove passpoint wifi network on iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, network, wifi

I'm having this issue on my iPhone where it connects automatically to a certain network (Orange Mobile WIFI). These things are all around town but they do not work at all. The thing is that I can't even remove the network because there is no "forget this network" button. Has anyone else had this issue and how can I permanently remove the network? (iOS 9.3.3, jailbroken)

Comment: If you tap the "i" button near the network name, is there a switch that says "auto-join"?

Comment: Do you have any other wifi networks saved on your iPhone?

Comment: You should have a button on top after tapping the 'i' besides the network name saying 'Ignore network'. That should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

My iPhone was trying to connect to TWC Wifi Passpoint after I deleted the Time Warner app. Even when I adjusted my wifi setting, it persisted. I resolved the issue by going into Settings -> General -> Profiles and removing the TWC profile.

Answer (score 1):

There’s definitely a bug somewhere.

I’ve deleted the Time Warner profile, reset my iPhone X running iOS 13.3 network settings, and rebooted it several times.

When I click the info button for the secure TWC passpoint network, it does not show the usual auto-join, auto-login, or “Forget this Network” buttons.

My phone is still trying to connect everything it detects the network and still prompts me randomly for passwords.

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM was my iPhone WiFi keeps on trying to connect to TWC WiFi Passpoint or Spectrum WiFi even with Auto Join turn off.

SOLUTION 1. Go to your iPhone SETTINGS, then look and open the GENERAL Section and scroll all the way down until you see and open PROFILES section, once inside Remove or Delete TWC WiFi Profile.